# How to use $size in aggregate pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I need to get total number of documents in a collection based on a query. I using this code to get a result from DB, this return an array and then I 'extract' the length of this array, but sometimes I get an error of 16Mb limit. So what I'm looking for is a way to get an integer for the total amount of documents in this query

```
var result;
var pipeline =[
  {
    "$match": { 
      "submission_time": {
        "$gt": "Wed Jun 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (CST)",
        "$lt": "Wed Jun 15 2016 23:59:59 GMT-0600 (CST)" 
      } 
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": { 
      "account": 1,
      "ru_msgsnd": 1,
      "ru_minflt": 1,
      "slots": 1,
      "usage.cpu": 1,
      "usage.mem": 1,
      "submission_time": 1 
    }
  }
]
result = collection_name.aggregate(pipeline);
return result.length;
```

I forgot to mention that I'm writing this code using Meteor in the server side, since this collection is over 250K documents

thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: Two things I've noticed with your query: your dates are stored as string, using the comparison operators against the string field will not yield the same result as comparing against proper `Date()` objects as precision is greatly reduced. Secondly, with proper dates, you don't necessarily need the aggregation framework to do the query count as `count()` will do just as fine.

Comment: Hi @chridam this is just an example, in my real code I use a Date object a `$limit`, and the query works as expected. After that I reuse the code to get the actual total without `$limit` but then I get into this problem. The problem with .count() is that I'm doing this from my meteor app. Thanks again for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a package [tmeasday:publish-counts](https://atmospherejs.com/tmeasday/publish-counts) for publishing counts. However they say its not recommended if your data is large.

Instead of using aggregate, you should be using a publication to publish the counts. You can find the example to publish counts() [here](https://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html). Hope this will help you.